# How to set NSpredicate with AND condition to fetch Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-data, nspredicate

I am developing one iPad application using storyboard and core data .For my application need to fetch the data based on two condition. langCode = 'ESP' and code = 'P0001'. I set the NSPredicate in the following format

```
 NSString *language= @"ESP";
 NSString *itemCode = @"P0001";
 NSPredicate *predicateCardText = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(langCode == %@)AND (code == %@)", language,itemCode];
```

But the fetch request returns empty array.I checked the database the object with langCode =ESP and code =P0001 is available in the database.But if I set AND condition in my NSPredicate,  it returns empty array.

Comment: I tend to use "AND", and that works without issue for me. So I'm not sure thats really the answer.

Comment: It makes no differerence if you use "AND" or `&&`. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @Martin R I have data is my database when i set each condition separately the fetch request return the data.

Comment: You can set the command line argument `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3` in the scheme editor. Then the generated SQLite query is printed to the console. That might help to locate the problem.

Comment: @MartinR i am new in iOS would you help me to set com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3

Comment: @user3762713: Goto "Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme …". Select the "Arguments" tab. In the "Arguments Passed On Launch" section, click "+". Enter "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug".

Comment: @user3762713: In addition, you could show the output of `NSLog(@"predicate=%@", predicateCardText)` .

Comment: @MartinR i set -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug.Show the o/p like... langCode == "ESP" AND code == "PC0001"

Comment: @user3762713: I cannot see an obvious error in your predicate. Are you sure that there are objects satisfying *both* criteria simultaneously?

Comment: @MartinR yes sure.I checked in using core data editor.

Answer (score 1):

Same as you would in Code:

```
     NSString *language= @"ESP";
     NSString *itemCode = @"P0001";
     NSPredicate *predic ateCardText = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"langCode == %@ && code == %@", language,itemCode];
```

Comment: I might be overlooking something, but this predicate should be equivalent to the one in the question.

Comment: And you're sure there are objects that have both that language and item code ?